# own very simple CMS system

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to make my own CMS system, like Joomla or Drupal. Now, I can add and delete articles and I have to log in as administrator. I use php and mysql and Jquery.

And now, I want to solve, that I can add and remove menus and menu points. The problem is, when I create new menu item (e.g.:About us), I should create a new php file (aboutus.php). But I don't know, is there any way in php, that I create another php file from a php, like I can create a simple txt file? Or I should use mysql? Or what is the best way, to solve my problem?

Comment: Please don't say CMS System since CMS stands for Content Management *System* ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411656/how-to-create-php-files-using-php - create php with php

Comment: You'd be better off making it so the page content was stored in the database for aboutus and then load that page content using url variables like website.com/aboutus (with mod rewrite) or website.com/index.php?page=aboutus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a file is not the way to go. You have to create an `index.php` which catches all requests and in that file it has to be determined what to do. If About Us is a page created in the CMS, you'll probably want to load a template page filled with the About Us page contents from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this is not the right way for doing this. This is one of the example for creating files.

```
$content = "some text here";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myFile.php","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```